# working with buffer in python

Tags: python, buffer

I am working with buffers in python but faced to some problems.
I searched for buffer's working tools in python, some thing like what is in nodejs but did not find any thing like this: [nodejs_buffer](http://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_buffer)

Is there any library or module in python like what is in nodejs?
thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working with binary data in Python is usually done using `str` objects in Python 2 and `bytes` objects in Python 3. These are immutable, but can be conveniently concatenated.

Then there is the mutable `bytearray` class.